# Git flow in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, git-flow

What would be the best way to implement git-flow using pipeline plugin ?

I am trying to implement git-flow branching strategy in a pipeline task.
Please correct me If I am wrong, but as far as I understand pipeline plugin, it' purpose is to create a script capable of handling multiple repository branches.

I know of *Pipeline Multibranch Plugin* and it looks like using it could make things easier for me, but for this particular repository I can *NOT* keep Jenkinsfile with the build script in the same place as the source code.

In my script I am trying to detect the branch on which the last change was pushed, I used:

```
echo "My branch is: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
```

But this return null

I also tried with

```
def getBranch() {
    sh 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD > GIT_BRANCH'
    git_branch = readFile('GIT_BRANCH').trim()
    return git_branch
}
```

but this one always returns master, despite the fact that the last push, that triggered the build was made on a feature branch.

From what I've found, this might be the source of my problems

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36436

What would be the best way to circumvent it ?

Comment: It appears your blocking issue has been resolved as https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100